# App.jsx:43 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.concerts.map is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dom, api-design

I keep getting this error when I'm trying to render json from the ticketmaster api in my App.jsx. The url I have on my backend is pulling the data to show the first 10 concert results. It shows up perfectly fine in my react console in chrome, put when I try to map the results to a div, I get this error message. Please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      concerts: [],
    }
    this.handleZip = this.handleZip.bind(this);
 }
  handleZip(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let zip = e.target.value;
    if (zip) {
      fetch(`api/services/ticketmaster/shows/${zip}`)
      .then((response) => {
        response.json().then(concerts => this.setState({
          concerts: concerts._embedded,
      // name: Object.values(concerts._embedded.events[0].images[0]),
      // image: concerts._embedded.events[0].images[0],
      // url: concerts._embedded.events[0].url,
      // info: concerts._embedded.events[0].info,
      // date: concerts._embedded.events[0].classifications[0].name,
        }));
      });
    }
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-container">
        <div className="zipcode-search-bar">
        <input onBlur={this.handleZip} type="text" placeholder="Enter      your zip code" />
        </div>
        <div className="zipcode-search-btn">
          <button className="zip-btn" onBlur=    {this.handleZip}>Search</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        {
          this.state.concerts.map((concert) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {concert}
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And this is what the data from ticketmaster looks like in postman:

```
   {
  "_embedded": {
    "events": [
      {
    "name": "Big Gigantic",
    "type": "event",
    "id": "k7vGFfodZESLi",
    "test": false,
    "url": "http://ticketmaster.com/event/00005110C09F37EC",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "images": [
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-    b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_EVENT_DETAIL_PAGE_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 205,
        "height": 115,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_LARGE_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 2048,
        "height": 1152,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 1136,
        "height": 639,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "3_2",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_3_2.jpg",
        "width": 1024,
        "height": 683,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 1024,
        "height": 576,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "3_2",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_PORTRAIT_3_2.jpg",
        "width": 640,
        "height": 427,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_PORTRAIT_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 640,
        "height": 360,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "16_9",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RECOMENDATION_16_9.jpg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 56,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "3_2",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_ARTIST_PAGE_3_2.jpg",
        "width": 305,
        "height": 203,
        "fallback": false
      },
      {
        "ratio": "4_3",
        "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_CUSTOM.jpg",
        "width": 305,
        "height": 225,
        "fallback": false
      }
    ],
    "sales": {
      "public": {
        "startDateTime": "2016-09-09T14:00:00Z",
        "startTBD": false,
        "endDateTime": "2016-11-06T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "presales": [
        {
          "startDateTime": "2016-09-07T14:00:00Z",
          "endDateTime": "2016-09-09T02:00:00Z",
          "name": "Venue Presale"
        }
      ]
    },
    "dates": {
      "start": {
        "localDate": "2016-11-05",
        "localTime": "21:00:00",
        "dateTime": "2016-11-06T01:00:00Z",
        "dateTBD": false,
        "dateTBA": false,
        "timeTBA": false,
        "noSpecificTime": false
      },
      "timezone": "America/New_York",
      "status": {
        "code": "offsale"
      }
    },
    "classifications": [
      {
        "primary": true,
        "segment": {
          "id": "KZFzniwnSyZfZ7v7nJ",
          "name": "Music"
        },
        "genre": {
          "id": "KnvZfZ7vAvF",
          "name": "Dance/Electronic"
        },
        "subGenre": {
          "id": "KZazBEonSMnZfZ7vAJ1",
          "name": "Club Dance"
        }
      }
    ],
    "promoter": {
      "id": "653",
      "name": "LIVE NATION MUSIC",
      "description": "LIVE NATION MUSIC / NTL / USA"
    },
    "info": "Big Gigantic has always been dedicated to giving back to those in need through their #ABigGiganticDifference Initiative. On this Brighter Future tour, they will continue the #ABigGiganticDifference mission by donating a percentage of ticket sales from each show to a local nonprofit of charity in need in each city. In our city of Huntington, they will be supporting the mission to collect toys for children in need by donating to Toys of Hope. If you'd like more information on Toys of Hope or would like to look into further volunteer or donation options with them, please visit http://www.toysofhope.org/contact_us.html. Thank you for continuing to support their initiative and by purchasing a ticket to this show, you are truly making #ABigGiganticDifference in our city!",
    "priceRanges": [
      {
        "type": "standard",
        "currency": "USD",
        "min": 25,
        "max": 66
      }
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "/discovery/v2/events/k7vGFfodZESLi?locale=en-us"
      },
      "attractions": [
        {
          "href": "/discovery/v2/attractions/K8vZ917GRLf?locale=en-us"
        },
        {
          "href": "/discovery/v2/attractions/K8vZ9173V70?locale=en-us"
        }
      ],
      "venues": [
        {
          "href": "/discovery/v2/venues/KovZpZAEAEtA?locale=en-us"
        }
      ]
    },
    "_embedded": {
      "venues": [
        {
          "name": "The Paramount",
          "type": "venue",
          "id": "KovZpZAEAEtA",
          "test": false,
          "url": "http://ticketmaster.com/venue/1280",
          "locale": "en-us",
          "postalCode": "11743",
          "timezone": "America/New_York",
          "city": {
            "name": "Huntington"
          },
          "state": {
            "name": "New York",
            "stateCode": "NY"
          },
          "country": {
            "name": "United States Of America",
            "countryCode": "US"
          },
          "address": {
            "line1": "370 New York Ave"
          },
          "location": {
            "longitude": "-73.42591099",
            "latitude": "40.86969685"
          },
          "markets": [
            {
              "id": "35"
            },
            {
              "id": "124"
            }
          ],
          "dmas": [
            {
              "id": 296
            },
            {
              "id": 345
            }
          ],
          "social": {
            "twitter": {
              "handle": "@TheParamountNY"
            }
          },
          "boxOfficeInfo": {
            "phoneNumberDetail": "For more information please visit paramountny.com VIP Seating and Packages: Please call 631-673-7300 or visit paramountny.com",
            "acceptedPaymentDetail": "Cash, Visa, MasterCard, Discover, Diners Club, & American Express",
            "willCallDetail": "Location : Main Lobby Opens : 1 hour prior to show or event"
          },
          "parkingDetail": "For parking information please visit : paramountny.com",
          "accessibleSeatingDetail": "This is an accessible venue.",
          "generalInfo": {
            "generalRule": "NO cameras NO recording NO outside food or beverages (including alcohol) Backpacks and large bags must must be checked. ALL bags are subject to search. Smoking is NOT permitted",
            "childRule": "Everyone needs a ticket to enter"
          },
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/discovery/v2/venues/KovZpZAEAEtA?locale=en-us"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "attractions": [
        {
          "name": "Big Gigantic",
          "type": "attraction",
          "id": "K8vZ917GRLf",
          "test": false,
          "url": "http://ticketmaster.com/artist/1474639",
          "locale": "en-us",
          "images": [
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_EVENT_DETAIL_PAGE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 205,
              "height": 115,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_LARGE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 2048,
              "height": 1152,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 1136,
              "height": 639,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 1024,
              "height": 683,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 1024,
              "height": 576,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_PORTRAIT_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 640,
              "height": 427,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RETINA_PORTRAIT_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 640,
              "height": 360,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_RECOMENDATION_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 100,
              "height": 56,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_ARTIST_PAGE_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 305,
              "height": 203,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "4_3",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/2e6/6c23d561-98d7-4025-b49a-5e20544c52e6_153341_CUSTOM.jpg",
              "width": 305,
              "height": 225,
              "fallback": false
            }
          ],
          "classifications": [
            {
              "primary": true,
              "segment": {
                "id": "KZFzniwnSyZfZ7v7nJ",
                "name": "Music"
              },
              "genre": {
                "id": "KnvZfZ7vAvF",
                "name": "Dance/Electronic"
              },
              "subGenre": {
                "id": "KZazBEonSMnZfZ7vAJ1",
                "name": "Club Dance"
              }
            }
          ],
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/discovery/v2/attractions/K8vZ917GRLf?locale=en-us"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Illenium",
          "type": "attraction",
          "id": "K8vZ9173V70",
          "test": false,
          "url": "http://ticketmaster.com/artist/2035639",
          "locale": "en-us",
          "images": [
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_RETINA_PORTRAIT_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 640,
              "height": 360,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_ARTIST_PAGE_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 305,
              "height": 203,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/c/df8/81eadad8-4449-412e-a2b1-3d8bbb78edf8_106181_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 1024,
              "height": 576,
              "fallback": true
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_EVENT_DETAIL_PAGE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 205,
              "height": 115,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "4_3",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_CUSTOM.jpg",
              "width": 305,
              "height": 225,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/c/df8/81eadad8-4449-412e-a2b1-3d8bbb78edf8_106181_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_LARGE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 2048,
              "height": 1152,
              "fallback": true
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_RECOMENDATION_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 100,
              "height": 56,
              "fallback": false
            },
            {
              "ratio": "16_9",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/c/df8/81eadad8-4449-412e-a2b1-3d8bbb78edf8_106181_RETINA_LANDSCAPE_16_9.jpg",
              "width": 1136,
              "height": 639,
              "fallback": true
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/c/df8/81eadad8-4449-412e-a2b1-3d8bbb78edf8_106181_TABLET_LANDSCAPE_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 1024,
              "height": 683,
              "fallback": true
            },
            {
              "ratio": "3_2",
              "url": "http://s1.ticketm.net/dam/a/9c1/12b833e2-a349-4e59-b02a-9cad62cab9c1_118101_RETINA_PORTRAIT_3_2.jpg",
              "width": 640,
              "height": 427,
              "fallback": false
            }
          ],
          "classifications": [
            {
              "primary": true,
              "segment": {
                "id": "KZFzniwnSyZfZ7v7nJ",
                "name": "Music"
              },
              "genre": {
                "id": "KnvZfZ7vAvF",
                "name": "Dance/Electronic"
              },
              "subGenre": {
                "id": "KZazBEonSMnZfZ7vAJ1",
                "name": "Club Dance"
              }
            }
          ],
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/discovery/v2/attractions/K8vZ9173V70?locale=en-us"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is `concerts._embedded` really an array ?

Comment: it's an object that holds an array of objects. I'll add the postman data

Comment: If you want to map over something, it has to be an array, so when you do your `setState({concerts})`, provide an array.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid

Comment: So add the array after the .then but before the setState({concerts})?

Comment: 1) what do you want to show in the jsx `{concert}` ? 2) Where is it located in the json back from your api ? 3) Correctly prepare that data inside an array of objects that you provide to the `.setState` you call after your API call

Comment: _embedded is an object not an array? Is this the full output?

Comment: yes. if I do concerts._embedded.events, events is the array of objects

Comment: that is the full output too. it shows up fine in my react console. all the data shows up when I search by zip code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the inner `events` array rather than the outer `_embedded` object. You can do this in one of two ways.

Set the state to hold the inner `events` array

```
response.json().then(concerts => this.setState({
          concerts: concerts._embedded.events,
      // name: Object.values(concerts._embedded.events[0].images[0]),
      // image: concerts._embedded.events[0].images[0],
      // url: concerts._embedded.events[0].url,
      // info: concerts._embedded.events[0].info,
      // date: concerts._embedded.events[0].classifications[0].name,
        }));
```

*or*

Access the inner the inner `events` array when the state is used

```
this.state.concerts.events.map((concert) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {concert}
    </div>
  );
})
```

Comment: Glad to help. Can you mark the answer as accepted please, and upvote it if you are feeling generous :-)